# Move TFS2010 to a domain

Tags: dns, upgrade, workgroup

I am trying to move my TFS2010 server to a domain and keep getting `TF246017` database error. I followed the instructions on:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

I shut down the service, I have no Sharepoint and the next point was to move user and service accounts.

I did(with an admin account):

1. `cd "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools"`
2. `TFSConfig identities /change /fromdomain:OLS-APPServer /todomain:NewDomain /account:"NT Authority\Local Service" /toaccount:"NT Authority\Local Service"`

and that is where I got a :

> "TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database.
>   Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational,
>   and that network problems are not blocking communication with the
>   server."

The SQL server is local and I can connect to it via SSMS. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you add more details on how you moved to a domain?  Did you move boxes or did you just make the WG joined machine join a domain?

Comment: The machine (serverA) was part of a workgroup and I just wanted it to join the domain. I rename the machine and join the domain in one step. The SQL start but I cannot use the TFS admin console to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that there's a /sqlInstance & /databaseName parameter.  That may help the command find your db.  Point it to the sql instance (machineName, machineName\InstanceName etc...) and db (Tfs_Configuration)

> (toolsPath)>tfsconfig help identities Logging sent to file
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server
>   Configuration\Logs\CFG_CFG_UNK_1026_173837.log Microsoft (R) TfsConfig
>   - Team Foundation Server Configuration Tool Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Command: help Microsoft (R) TfsConfig - Team Foundation Server
>   Configuration Tool Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> TfsConfig identities /change /fromdomain: /todomain:
>                                  [/account: [/toaccount:]]
>                                  [/sqlInstance:
>                                   /databaseName:]

Also, Local Service is not appropriate for a domain TFS.  Have you tried to change the account to Network Service or a domain account?

Try:
    tfsconfig help accounts

Look at the change option.  You can also specify the sqlInstance and databaseName options there as well.

```
TfsConfig accounts /change /accountType:applicationTier
                   /account:"NT Authority\Network Service"
```